# how to enable grid view columns

Tags: c#, asp.net

am created one multi view in this grid one particular user only adding comments.other user is not edited. if am taken in this grid template this template am taken text box for writing comments . now i want to how to enable text box in this grid.

and i write counting the date but it not working how to i fix this one

```
EP_LeaveManagementRow urnewleave = new EP_LeaveManagementRow();
                urnewleave.LeaveAppliedFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.Trim());
                urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text.Trim());



                if (urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate > urnewleave.LeaveAppliedFromDate)
                {
                    //int Days = urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate.Subtract(urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate
                  TimeSpan NoOfDays = urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate - urnewleave.LeaveAppliedFromDate;
                  lblNoOfDays.Text = NoOfDays.ToString();

                    {
                         // User Details
                        EP_UserDetailsRow urnewdet = new EP_UserDetailsRow();
                        urnewdet.FirstName = txtEmpName.Text;
                        urnewdet.EmpID = txtEmpID.Text;
                        //Manager Details
                        EP_UserRow usnewdet = new EP_UserRow();
                        //usnewdet.MangerUserID= int.Parse(ddlMangaer.SelectedItem.Value);
                         // Apply leave Details
                        urnewleave.LeaveType = Convert.ToInt32(ddlLeaveType.SelectedValue.ToString());
                        urnewleave.LeaveAppliedFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.Trim());
                        urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text.Trim());
                        //lblNoOfDays.Text = ""+((urnewleave.LeaveAppliedFromDate > urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate)) ?(urnewleave.LeaveAppliedFromDate - urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate).TotalDays :(urnewleave.LeaveAppliedToDate - urnewleave.LeaveAppliedFromDate).TotalDays);

                        urnewleave.LeaveReson = txtReason.Text;
                        urnewleave.UserID = int.Parse(Session["UserID"].ToString());

                        urnewleave.CreatedBy = logUser.UserID;
                        urnewleave.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        urnewleave.ModifiedBy = logUser.UserID;
                        urnewleave.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        urnewleave.LeaveStatus = Convert.ToInt32(ddlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString()); 
                        db.EP_LeaveManagementCollection.Insert(urnewleave);
                        BindLeaveManagementDetails();
                        mvLeaveManagement.SetActiveView(vwLeavesDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply u can do it by this:

```
myDataGridView1.Enabled = true;
```

This will enable all of ur TextBox allow for edit.